# c# Alterar Propriedades de controle de outro arquivo

Tags: c#

eu tenho 2 forms(a login e a programa) pelo login da pessoa eu qro que um dos 2 paineis (dentro do programa tem 2 paneis para cada tipo de login: o adm e funcionario) vá para frente porém Login.CS não estou conseguindo puxar os panels no condigo para fazer o bring to front e ambos estão no mesmo namespace

```
            if (Olho.HasRows)
            {
                Roteador Form1 = new Roteador();
                this.Hide();
                Form1.Show();
                Olho.Read();
                int Valor = Convert.ToInt32(Olho[1]);

                if(Valor == 1)
                {
                  *aqui eu colocaria o Panel.BringToFront
                }
                else
                {
                  *aqui eu colocaria o Panel.BringToFront
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ter acesso a um objecto de outra classe esse objecto não pode ser **private**

Coloque um **getter** para ter acesso a esse objecto.

em *Login.cs*

```
public Panel Panel1
{
    get { return this.panel1; }
}

public Panel Panel2
{
    get { return this.panel2; }
}
```

BringToFront é um metodo, precisa de parênteses no final.

```
frmLogin.Panel1.BringToFront();
```